# Difference IE and Webkit

Tags: css, internet-explorer, webkit

This is my code for a nice looking form:

```
<dl>
    <dt class='breed'><label for="nwberichten">Fieldname</label></dt>
    <dd>
        Input
    </dd>
    <div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>
</dl>
<dl class='oe'>
        <dt class='breed'><label for="nwberichten">Fieldname</label></dt>
        <dd>
            Input
        </dd>
        <div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>
    </dl>
```

With the folowing CSS

```
dl {margin-top:0px;}
dt {float:left; text-align:right; width:120px; line-height:25px; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}
dd {float:left; width:400px; line-height:25px; margin:0 0 10px 0;}
DL  {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #aaa;
    margin:0px;
    line-height:20px;
    padding-top:6px;;
}

DL DD   {
    line-height:20px;
    background:transparent;
}
DT  {
    line-height:20px;
    background:transparent;
}
DL.oe   {
    background:#efe;
}
```

In webkit (eg Safari) the Uneven row, the one with the BG color #efe looks perfect. The bgcolor goes from one dashed border to the other. 
In IE the color is only 10px (or so) high and the looks are messed up.

How is this possible?

Comment: Could you link to a live repro? It would be easier to debug this if we could load the page up in a browser.

Comment: This could be acheived without `<dl>` as well, and would be slightly more semantic.

Comment: I could also use div's instead; but somebody else already choose the defenition list.
Besides, the form defines how the webpage should work: so a definition list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll briefly explain what I did and why. The code is at the end.

The first mistake is using clearing `div`s inside the `dl` element. A `dl` can only contain `dd`s and `dt`s. To achieve clearing you can set `overflow` to `hidden` for your `dl`s. It achieves the same effect. This is also probably why your page looks a bit messed up in IE (because of the `div`s in the `dl`s)

As for the rest, I just cleaned up your CSS a bit.

HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt class="breed"><label for="nwberichten">Fieldname</label></dt>
    <dd>
        Input
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="oe">
    <dt class="breed"><label for="nwberichten">Fieldname</label></dt>
    <dd>
        Input
    </dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl { margin:0; padding-top:6px; overflow:hidden; border-bottom:1px dashed #aaa; }
dl.oe { background:#efe; }
dt, dd { float:left; line-height:25px; background:transparent; }
dt { text-align:right; width:120px; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}
dd { width:400px; margin:0 0 10px 0;}
```